# Autosuggest with circle not returning available suggestions

Tags: here-api, autosuggest

When using HERE autosuggest we send the following request:

https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?q=STATIONSGATAN&in=circle:65.82,21.70;r=50000&apiKey=XXXXXXXX&limit=10

The request only return three items which are close to lat: 65.82 and long: 21.70. But I know that there's an address called 'STATIONSGATAN' 37000 meters from this point that isn't available in the response.

Can someone help me understand why addresses that matches my request isn't being returned in the response? I think an address that matches the query and is within the requested radius should be returned when the limit is set to 10.